# What is the correct electron dot notation of carbon?

Tags: notation, lewis-structure

My book says that the dot notation for Lewis structure of carbon has 2 possible ways:

1. two dots on the right, one on the top, one on the left
2. one dot on all four sides

Why are both of these correct? Isn't only the first one correct by Hund's rule? By the way, we are now learning Lewis structures and the book randomly used the 2nd dot notation of carbon.

Comment: why is it allowed to move around the valence electrons for bonding?

Comment: Both are correct. Electrons are free to move around the atom. They change position all the time. Don't forget they may move and repel each other.

Comment: oh ok, so it is allowed for a valence electron to move from s sublevel to p sublevel and vice versa freely?

Comment: Umm, you're not really asking about dumb dot drawings there... It's  not "freely" at all in reality. Four unpaired electrons are high excited state, but I kinda doubt people using "dot structures" usually care about it.

Comment: @Maurice There's this dumb rule with drawing dots in pairs in "dot structures".  It's no wonder you didn't get OP's question though, as like no-one serious about chemistry cares about them IMO.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_carbon#Electromagnetic_properties) is how it works, but you don't really need to know it.